# Download SQL 2008 R2 and install remotely with key

Tags: sql-server-2008, licensing

I have the media and product key for a copy of SQL Server 2008R2, however, I can not get my CD to the server at my data center. Is there a downloadable version (or can the trial be downloaded) of the application that I can install and apply my key to?

Thanks

Comment: https://licensing.microsoft.com/

Comment: Why not copy the contents of the CD/DVD to the datacenter server?